# Dynamically render file parameter in Jenkins

Tags: user-interface, jenkins, dynamic, parameters, rendering

For dynamic rendering, I use the below plugin.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/

However, there is no option for dynamic rendering of a "file parameter".

Is it possible to dynamically render "file parameters" based on a selection from a drop-down list for a job DSL or for a pipeline?

Thus if the user selects option1 from the drop-down then 3 file parameters should appear when the user selects option 2 no file parameters and with option three only 1 file parameter should render.

Comment: I which way the file parameters should depend on a selection from a drop-down list?

Comment: yes that's what I want @zett42

Comment: Can you add some details? What should happen when the selection from drop-down list changes?

Comment: You could use Active Choice Dynamic Reference parameter, choice type "Formatted HTML" to render one or more file input elements depending on another parameter. But in pipeline there are [issues with file parameters](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38893), don't know about job DSL though.